# VBA to find a word in a range and copy all cells beginning with the same word

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with my routine. I have a row (2) in which there is a number of populated cells. At one instance I have a couple (the number changes every now and again) cells consecutively starting with the word Blue (and ending with a number 1, 2 ,3 4 etc.). Ignoring the numbers, I would like to copy all cells (as a range?) starting with the word Blue*. I have managed to get one cell find and copy with the below code:

```
Sub findcopy()
  Dim rFound As Range
  
  Set rFound = Sheets("page 1").Rows(2).Find(What:="Blue", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If Not rFound Is Nothing Then rFound.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("page 1").Range("AG2")

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should do the job.I will try to refine it a bit more but at the moment this is working. Still, I will welcome other **answers** (and accept if better) and suggestions before I accept my own. Thanks

```
Sub SearchX()
Dim c, destination As Range, i As Long
Const SEARCH_TERM As String = "Blue"
Set destination = ActiveSheet.Range("AA10")
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("B2:BB2")
i = 1
Do While InStr(i, c.Value, SEARCH_TERM) > 0
destination.Value = c.Value
Set destination = destination.Offset(1, 0)
i = InStr(i, c.Value, SEARCH_TERM) + Len(SEARCH_TERM)
Loop
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, which is faster (but maybe only noticeable with sizeable data), is to

- Read the range into a vba array
- process the array by collecting the relevant data into some object designed for that
- create an output array of the relevant data and write it back to the worksheet

The above is faster because you only access the worksheet twice; and worksheet access is a slow part of VBA. Speed increase can be up to an order of magnitude.

In the code below, I chose to use an ArrayList as the collection object. But you could use other objects.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub findAndCopy()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, rRes As Range, V As Variant
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim AL As Object
    
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet2")
With wsSrc
    'read data into array
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    
    'set the output range Cell 1
    Set rRes = wsSrc.Cells(10, 1)
End With

Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

'collect the relevant data
For Each V In vSrc
    If V Like "Blue*" Then _
        AL.Add V
Next V

'resize the output range
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=1, columnsize:=AL.Count)

'write results to output range and format
With rRes
    .EntireRow.Clear
    .Value = AL.toarray
    .Style = "Output" 'optional and will vary depending on language
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
     
End Sub
```

In addition to the MS documentation, I have found [this article](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/) helpful in understanding Array Lists and its use.

For this purpose, the coding seems simpler than using a Dictionary or Collection object.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I'll test it tonight. Appreciate your time.